# GROCERY CRUD date picker widget?

Tags: php, codeigniter, datepicker, widget, grocery-crud

It is given that if your column type is date the form will show a date picker using the grocery crud. My problem is that, is it possible to use the date picker widget of the GROCERY CRUD (like displaying the date picker in the view and return the picked date)? If yes, how? An example will be appreciated.

Comment: You want to use the date picker outside of the CRUD?

Comment: @AlexW yes. I need a date picker to give date range for my sql query. My plan is instead of adding jQuery for date picker, I will recycle the date picker from the grocery crud.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the [jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

So, assuming you have all of the same stylesheets and scripts included, in the view you want to use it on, as you do in the CRUD view, you can just use code like this (let's say your input field's `id` attribute is equal to "element"):

```
$("#element").datepicker();
```

Or, you can add a class to all of the elements you want to have date pickers (let's say `date-picker`), and then run this JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.date-picker').datepicker();
});
```